# Scraping a webpage that constantly updates

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping

Thanks for taking some time to check out this question.

I'm trying to scrape public bids data from the [CAISO website](http://oasis.caiso.com/mrioasis/logon.do). And I'm running into these problems:

a. The page is constantly updating, so I think that my code is
    getting stuck.

b. The XML objects tags change at every new session.

For (a), I tried using time.sleep and sending an ESC key to stop the refreshing, but it's not working.

I don't know how to solve (b), though. What I typically do is I use this Chrome extension that allows me to get the XML elements in a page and I use those in my code to do what I want. If they change everytime, this strategy doesn't work anymore.

What I want Selenium to do is:

1. Open 'http://oasis.caiso.com/mrioasis/logon.do'
2. Click on PUBLIC BIDS>Public Bids
3. Loop over a list of dates, downloading the CSV files for each.

Here's my code so far:

```
driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get('http://oasis.caiso.com/mrioasis/logon.do')
PublicBids = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, '//*[@id="IMG_111854124"]')
PublicBids.click()

dates = ['04/18/2019']

def BidsScraper(d):
    time.sleep(2)
    dateField = driver.find_element(By.XPATH,'//*[@id="TB_101685670"]')
    dateField.send_keys(d)
    DownloadCSV = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, '//*[@id="BTN_101685706"]')
    DownloadCSV.click()
```

Any suggestions are welcome! Thanks again.

EDIT: formatting

Answer (score 0):

One way to approach this is to find the elements / buttons you want relative to some static Ids, instead of going directly to the element's dynamic Id.

I don't know the exact XPath, but for example the `div` wrapping the date input has an Id of `PFC_Public_Bids_date_from`, so you could try something like

`dateField = driver.find_element(By.XPATH,'//*[@id="PFC_Public_Bids_date_from"]//input')`.

Similarly the button could be something like:

`DownloadCSV = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, '//*[@id="CsvExportButton"]//button')`

Comment: Thank you for your quick response! I'll try it now.

Answer (score 0):

A couple of things to try is forcing the refresh to stop and clicking only if the element is found with Selenium, or if that still doesn't work for you, I usually try something like moving the mouse to the X/Y coordinates with a macro program like AppRobotic Personal and then simulating a mouse click on the button's X/Y coordinates. Something similar to this in a Try/Except:

```
import win32com.client
x = win32com.client.Dispatch("AppRobotic.API")
from selenium import webdriver

driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get('http://oasis.caiso.com/mrioasis/logon.do')
PublicBids = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, '//*[@id="IMG_111854124"]')
PublicBids.click()
dates = ['04/18/2019']

def BidsScraper(d):
    # wait for loading
    x.Wait(2000)
    # forcefully stop page reload at this point
    driver.execute_script("window.stop();")
    try:
        dateField = driver.find_element(By.XPATH,'//*[@id="TB_101685670"]')
        dateField.send_keys(d)
        DownloadCSV = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, '//*[@id="BTN_101685706"]')
    #Confirm that button was found
        if len(DownloadCSV) > 0
            DownloadCSV.click()
    except:
        dateField = driver.find_element(By.XPATH,'//*[@id="TB_101685670"]')
        x.Type(d)
        # use UI Item Explorer to find the X,Y coordinates of button
        x.MoveCursor(438, 435)
        # click on button
        x.MouseLeftClick
    x.Wait(2000)
```